# comparing 2 UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have an array full of buttons and when a use clicks one I would like to search the array for it.

Yes, I have given the buttons tags, but they are used for another purpose.  So I am hoping that there is another way to check for equality.

I was hoping that I would be able to do something like `button1.frame.origin == button2.frame.origin`, but the compiler doesnt like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `bool CGRectEqualToRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2)`.  Just pass in both of the button's frames as parameters into this method and it'll return a bool stating whether they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` (and `UIView`) inherits from `NSObject` so you should just be able to do `isEqual`.

```
 if([button1 isEqual:button2])
    {
      // do whatever
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can compare memory addressed of those objects, same as isEqual method is using

```
NSArray *buttons=@[button1,button2,button3,button4];//your array of buttons
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;//button to search
    [buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton * button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (button==b) {
        //do your thing here...
        *stop=TRUE;

        }
    }];
```

Comment: -1, invalid array declaration for non mac OSX beta users, which doesn't help a lot of people.

Comment: the question is about comparison of objects, the array declaration is not meant to be used

Comment: just to mention: the NSArray literal syntax is available in iOS 6 Beta / Xcode 4.5 too. But you should just remove the declaration, as the OP stated that the array already exists. just to avoid confusion.